# Несколько callback функций в одном стеке

Tags: callback, javascript

Из примера думаю будет ясно что я имею в виду:

```
var preloadImages = function (imageIn) {
    var imageIn = (typeof imageIn !== "object") ? [imageIn] : imageIn;
    this.arrayImages = [];
    this.loadedimages = 0;
    var progressLoad = function () {

    }
    var completeLoad = function () {}
    var imageLoadCheck = function () {
        progressLoad(++this.loadedimages);
        if (this.loadedimages === imageIn.length) {
            completeLoad(this.arrayImages);
        }
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < imageIn.length; i++) {
        this.arrayImages[i] = new Image();
        this.arrayImages[i].src = imageIn[i];
        this.arrayImages[i].onload = function () {
            imageLoadCheck();
        }
        this.arrayImages[i].onerror = function () {
            imageLoadCheck();
        }
    }
    return {
        complete: function (f) {
            completeLoad = f || completeLoad;
        },
        progress: function (f) {
            progressLoad = f || progressLoad;
        }
    }
}

var imageList = ['1.jpg', '2.jpg', '3.jpg', '4.jpg', '5.jpg', '6.jpg', '7.jpg', '8.jpg', '9.jpg', '10.jpg'];

preloadImages(imageList).progress(function (namber) {
    console.log(namber);
}).complete(function (images) {
    console.log('Loading all image: ' + images.length);
})
```

Получаем: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'complete' of undefined
Подскажите как жеж правильно реализовывать подобное? или ткните пальцем где это написано, т.к. не нашел (

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Chaining pattern](https://github.com/shichuan/javascript-patterns/blob/master/object-creation-patterns/chaining.html), думаю, вам поможет. Перепишите функцию `preloadImages()` согласно этому паттерну, несколько видоизменив его. Вот простейший пример:

```
var preloadImages = function () {

    this.complete = function(f) {
        f();
        return this;
    }

    this.progress = function(f) {
        f();
        return this;
    }

    return this;
}

preloadImages().progress(function(){
    console.log('In progress')
}).complete(function(){
    console.log('Completed')
})
```

В консоли появляется:

```
In progress
Completed
Window {top: Window, window: Window, location: Location, external: Object, chrome: Object…}
```

Всё просто!

Comment: Спасибо, такой паттерн прошел мимо меня (

Comment: Без this: http://img.leprosorium.com/1770307